# flatMap deep chained Either-functions calls with fp-ts

Tags: typescript, types, either, fp-ts

is there a way to implement a deep record of async functions  returning `Either`s in such a way that a deep chained call finally returns the appropriate widened `Either` ?

```js
// this doesn't work
// but I hope it makes the idea

declare function a(): Either<ErrA, {
      b(): Either<ErrB, {
        c(): Either<ErrC, string>
      }>
    }
  >

const result = a().b().c() // Either<ErrA | ErrB | ErrC, string>
```

just like a `pipe( ...flatMap() )` would do.

my actual use case would have asyncrounous return types at each step, and the ideal api would look as follows:

```js
const result = await a().b().c() 
// result: E.Either<ErrA | ErrB | ErrC, string>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with fp-ts but I think it's interesting to note that as `await` roughly translates to `.then()` and thus is very much like flat mapping a thennable.